# Find which, if any, dictionary values exist in a string in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

So I'm finding ways to find if a key/value exists in a string, but I'm not finding any good examples that allow me to ACCESS the key/value that was found in the string.

Basically, I have a string. Let's say:

```
body = "Hi my name is John"
```

...and I have the following dictionary:

```
names = {"John": "John", "Bill": "Bill", "Jordan": "Jordan"}
```

I want to see if any of the names in the dictionary are contained in the string, and if so, I want to know which one it is (assign it to a variable or whatnot).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to search for words in a string? Do you know how to get a list of keys or values from a dictionary?

Comment: Why is `names` a dictionary where the values are the same as the keys?

Comment: karlson's response worked. I have the keys the same as the values because I wanted a dictionary for O(1) look-up time. Does List provide this in Python?

Comment: According to [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) a python list.GetItem() is indeed O(1). Though in my particular answer, I used sets.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please accept an answer (by clicking on the tick mark on the left side) or enter your own answer that worked for you instead. This way others know you are not still looking for answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a dict here, since the keys appear to be the same as the values: use a set instead. In the general case where the keys might have spaces in them (and even when they don't) you might find it easier to split the subject text into individual words, which you can do with the `spit()` method. So you could do something like the following.

```
body = "Hi my name is John"
names = {"John", "Bill", "Jordan"}
for word in body.split():
    if word in names:
        print(word)
```

This avoids having to search all the way through the string, and will probably be somewhat faster as well as making the intent of your code a little clearer.

Comment: But that will print all names each time a match is found. I don't believe that's what the OP intended. You probably meant `print(word)` instead of `print(names)`

Answer (score 0):

If I assume you have these mapped in a dictionary for a reason, I'll show you that yes it's possible to utilize those mappings in ways like this:

```
    class bodyTests():
        def __init__(self):
            self.nameMap = {"John": "Johnathon", "Johnathon": "Johnathon", "Bill": "William", "Wil": "William"}
            self.greetMap = {"Hi": "Hello", "aloha": "Hello", "Hello": "Hello", "Salutations": "Greetings"}

        def find(self, lookfor, searchin):
            return set(lookfor.get(x) for x in lookfor.viewkeys() & searchin.split())

        def findGuys(self, abody):
            return self.find(self.nameMap, abody)

        def findGreets(self, abody):
            return self.find(self.greetMap, abody)


    body = "Hi my name is John\nPlease call me John\nI wish I was named Bill"
    foundnames = bodyTests().findGuys(body)
    foundgreets = bodyTests().findGreets(body)
    print "python set of names: ", foundnames
    print "python set of greets: ", foundgreets
    print "let's dump them all out: "
    for s in foundnames:
        print s
    for s in foundgreets:
        print s
    exit()
```

> > python set of names:  set(['William', 'Johnathon'])
> >      python set of greets:  set(['Hello'])
> >      let's dump them all out:
> >      William
> >      Johnathon
> >      Hello

Answer (score -1):

This will give you a list of names that appear in `body`:

```
[name for name in names if name in body]
```

Having a dictionary where the key always equals the value seems somewhat suboptimal.

Comment: I think for someone just now learning python, that solution will appear as gibberish. You might want to add more explanation. Perhaps start with traditional lists, and then show how they can be collapsed into a comprehension. Then, show a fully working example with actual data.

Comment: Thank you! I just need the instant look-up time to check for existence. I'm not sure if List provides this in Python or not.

Comment: I think that reads almost like english, which is part of the beauty of Python. This is a very pythonic way of filtering, what's wrong about that even for a beginner?

Comment: @Matt, that's true, lists don't have constant lookup times, so I guess using a dictionary is fine in that case. However for a list of that size it will hardly make any difference.

Comment: It makes sense - I'm new to Python but I understand the concept of what that is. Is it a generator?

Comment: It's a list comprehension, but you can easily turn it into a generator by using round instead of square brackets.

Comment: @Matt Then again what's the point of fast lookup if you already know what's behind the key? It's always the key itself,  which you already have at the time of lookup.